# How to make device back button cause onCreate?

Tags: android

When you press back in ActionBar, it causes onCreate on the previous activity. How to do that with device back button aswell? In preference activity, if a certain preference is changed, I want main activity to be re-created when user presses back on bottom of their device.

Comment: Override onBackPressed and start a new activity adding the NEW_TASK flag to the intent.

Comment: Why do you want it to be re-created? That is not impossible but I doubt you are on the right track. And how did you manage having it re-created on ActionBar up button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) and start your Activity yourself.

You call [`onNavigateUp()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNavigateUp()) at any time in your Activity to get the same behavior as clicking the up button.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myPreferenceHasChanged) {
        onNavigateUp();
    } else {
        // Use the default behavior
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?This should solve your question

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // your code
    return true;
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```